# Is it possible to relate a master/child record using L2S or EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

**Edit: I am constrained to .Net 3.5...**

I have two objects/collections retrieved from a **stored procedure** in Linq to Sql (I could use EF if I have to). They are related with a 1 to many relationship both on the database, and in my database model. Can I relate these two obects so that I can Access them like:

```
ParentObject.ChildObjects.FirstOrDefault().Property
```

...without going back to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to specify eager loading of relationships in LINQ to SQL.. something like the following should work.

```
partial void OnCreated() {
    DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<ParentObject>(o => o.ChildObjects);
    this.LoadOptions = options;
}
```

That is specifying the options in the `OnCreate` partial of the data context, which is fine if you want the rule to persist through all instances but your case may be different.

I think there are some subtle nuances with loading of deeper nested objects just FYI.

It should also be noted that this just eager loads the related entities of the parent object when the parent object is requested, it does not do any magic to combine the query generated by the initial parent request. So in essence two queries will now be executed each time you request the parent instead of one, the advantage being that it will not go back to the database to retrieve the contents of the relationship upon enumeration because they will have already been loaded.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but not quite what I'm looking for. As the output of my stored procedure, I already have the master and child recordsets/collections. I'd like a way to glue them together so I can use them as standard linq to sql objects.

Comment: @jlnorsworth That is understandable and possible, I don't know how I missed the bold stored proc part of your question unless I had a previous version loaded and it was added after. You can create a method on your context to pull the different datasets out of an IMultipleResult (being the output of the proc) and then return the object with the specified dependent entities. Would you like an example?

Comment: I already have code to return an IMultipleResult, and pull the separate results out of it and into their own List<ObjectFromTable> using IMultipleResult.GetResult<MyTable>().ToList(). Is there more to it than that?